# Laravel selecting count (of rows created TODAY) using MySQL date functions

Tags: php, datetime, laravel

I want the the user to only be able to create a certain number submissions per day. This is what I used in CakePHP to get the number of submissions a user had made on that day and it worked:

```
$submitted_today = $this->Submission->find('count', array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Submission.ip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
                    'Submission.created >= CURRENT_DATE',
                    'Submission.created < CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 DAY'
                )
            ));
```

Here's what I came up with in Laravel:

```
$submitted_today = DB::table('submissions')
                    ->where('ip', '=', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
                    ->where('created', '>=', 'CURRENT_DATE')
                    ->where('created', '<', 'CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 DAY')
                    ->get();
```

But it doesn't work. What's wrong with it? Might it have something to with the MySQL date terms getting interpreted as strings?

---

**UPDATE:** Here's the code using whereRaw that (appears) to work.

```
$submitted_today = DB::table('submissions')
                    ->where('ip', '=', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
                    ->whereRaw('created >= CURRENT_DATE')
                    ->whereRaw('created < CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 DAY')
                    ->count();
```

Comment: exactly, they are interpreted as strings. use `DB::raw(...)`.

Comment: I couldn't get it working with DB::raw. I searched some more and discovered whereRaw and it appears to be working.

Comment: You use it like this: `where('created', '<=', DB::raw('CURRENT_DATE'))`, works exactly the same as your `whereRaw` code.

Answer (score 1):

Try using ->count() to get the no check [Laravel Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#aggregates)

```
$submitted_today = DB::table('submissions')
                    ->where('ip', '=', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
                    ->where('created', '>=', 'CURRENT_DATE')
                    ->where('created', '<', 'CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 DAY')
                    ->count();
```